# Powershell - Replace in memory xml node while iterating

Tags: xml, powershell

I've got the following xml:

```
<messages>
  <message name="Advertisement" msgtype="7" msgcat="app">
    <field name="AdvId" required="Y" />
    <field name="AdvTransType" required="Y" />
    <field name="AdvRefID" required="N" />
    <component name="Instrument" required="Y" />
    <field name="AdvSide" required="Y" />
    <field name="Quantity" required="Y" />
  </message>
</messages>
<components>
  <component name="Instrument">
    <field name="Symbol" required="Y" />
    <field name="SymbolSfx" required="N" />
    <field name="SecurityID" required="N" />
    <field name="SecurityIDSource" required="N" />
    <group name="NoSecurityAltID" required="N">
      <field name="SecurityAltID" required="N" />
      <field name="SecurityAltIDSource" required="N" />
    </group>
    <field name="Product" required="N" />
    <field name="CFICode" required="N" />
  </component>
</components>
```

I want to iterate over each message and when I encounter a `component` tag, I want to replace the component xml with the fields/groups of the component.

I was attempting to use `ReplaceChild`, but it wasn't working as expected.

```
  [void]LoadComponents() {
    $this.xml.messages.message | ForEach-Object {
      $m = $_
      foreach ($node in $m.ChildNodes){
        if ($node.LocalName -eq "component") {
          Write-Host "Old Message: "
          Write-Host ($m.field | Format-Table | Out-String)
          $c = $this.GetComponent($node.name)
          Write-Host "Component: "
          Write-Host ($c.group | Format-Table | Out-String)
          $m.ReplaceChild($c, $node)
          Write-Host "New Message: "
          Write-Host ($m.field | Format-Table | Out-String)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  [System.Xml.XmlElement]GetComponent([string]$name) {
    return $this.xml.components.component | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $name }
  }
```

#### Edit:

I'm including the fact that I'm using powershell version 6.0.0.10 alpha on OSX, because apparently it's missing a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath to select the component nodes directly and [clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlnode.clone.aspx) the replacement node in ReplaceChild.

```
$xml.SelectNodes('/root/messages/message/component') | ForEach {
    $comp = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/root/components/component[@name="' + $_.name + '"]')
    $message = $_.ParentNode
    $message.ReplaceChild($comp.Clone(), $_)
}
```

The code is assuming the root node is `root`.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, but I'm getting `[System.Xml.XmlDocument] does not contain a method named 'SelectNodes'`

Comment: powershell verion:  `6.0.0 alpha`

Comment: I don't use buggy/incomplete alpha versions so I have no idea how it could miss such basic functionality. It's as absurd as a String without IndexOf.